# Energy consumption by body

Tags: energy, everyday-life

i think the energy consumed by vertical jumping is too high when compared to the "2000 calorie a day requirement".

Say i weigh 60kg, i have studied my centre of mass from a video with wall markings, avg 50cm at peak jump vs standing straight.

Energy= 60*9.81*0.5= 294.3/ 4.18= 70.34 calories

And if friction, getting lower before the jump and landing energy is factored in, the resulting energy from one jump is atleast 140 calories.

Q1. So this means that i burn 2000 cal from just 14 jumps?
I did saw websites showing energy burned from sports in an hour, and they were like 900 cal at most.

Q2. What would be close approximation of exergy burned than simply >140 cal ?

(*That should explain why i cannot gain weight at all? because i do jumps as my only exercise because i need to save time. Im thin and trying to gain weight but cant.*)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong units for dietary calories. One dietary calorie is 1 kilocalorie. So your value of 70.34 calories is actually 0.07034 dietary calorie, and you only burn 2 dietary calories in 14 jumps.

One site quoted a range of 667-990 calories burned per hour jumping rope at 120 skips per minute, or a total of 7200 skips per hour. At the top of the range, that means 0.138 dietary calories per skip, or 1.9 calories per 14 skips. Matches up pretty well with your 2 calories per 14 jumps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that explains, thanks alot.but why they make it so confusing, using calories in both of them, scientific units should be precise i thought

Comment: @iuofk I agree with you. The dietary calorie is the energy unit used for the energy content of foods. I read on an NIH website that in early discussions of human energy needs circa 1870 the kcal was used in the discussions and that the thermal calorie was not fully defined until the 20th century, by which time the nutritional calorie was embedded in U.S. popular culture and nutritional policy.

Comment: In Germany  I think in all of Europe the "big calories, so the kcal are Cal with a capital C, the physical calories are cal.